# Scala boolean function abstraction

Tags: function, scala, abstraction

I have a function foo that accepts a Boolean function

```
def foo( f:(_)=>Boolean ) = //do something with f
```

I can call foo as follows

```
foo( (x:Int) => x == 0 )
```

Now, I want modify foo to accept any function that returns Boolean. eg. the modified foo should work for the following cases.

```
foo( (x:Int, y:Int) => x == y)
foo( (x:Int, y:Int, z:Int) => x == y && y == z)
foo( (x:Double, y:Double, z:Double, p:Double) => x < y && y < z && z < p)
//and so on...
```

My first attempt was to modify foo as follows

```
def foo2( f:(_*)=>Boolean ) = //do something with f
```

But this does not work.

Comment: What the "do something with f" really does? Can you show the code?

Comment: @n.m. Let me give some context. It is for a compiler plugin. The compiler plugin will extract a logical formula from the body of the function. The arguments of the functions are the free variables in the formula.

Comment: You seem to call a function with an unknown number of arguments. Can you show the code?

Comment: @n.m. I am not calling the function inside foo. In fact foo does nothing at runtime, it ignores the argument and just returns True. But when the source file is compiled, the compiler plugin extracts the logical formula from the abstract syntax tree of the body of the function. The formula is then used for compile time formal verification of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Nicolas said.

You can make the call site code slightly nicer using `Function.tupled`.

```
scala> def foo[A](f: A => Boolean) = 0
foo: [A](f: A => Boolean)Int

scala> import Function.tupled
import Function.tupled

scala> foo(tupled((x: Int, y: Int) => x == y))
res0: Int = 0

scala> foo(tupled((x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) => x < y && y < z))
res1: Int = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks clean. This will work for me for now. One thing to note however. This will not work for functions with more than 5 arguments. There is a note in Function.scala _"These functions are slotted for deprecation, but it is on hold pending superior type inference for tupling anonymous functions."_

Comment: @dips, the 5-argument thing is not a fundamental restriction. You can write your own tupling method in the same way as `Function.tupled` methods are written.

Comment: @dips, newer way to write this is `f.tupled` (instead of old `Function.tupled(f)`). As note says, the older way is friendlier with type inferer.

Answer (score 4):

Does it fit your need `def foo[A](pred: A => Boolean)`

For example:

```
def foo[A](pred: A => Boolean): A => Boolean = {x:A =>
  if (pred(x)) {
    println("Yeah!")
    true
  } else {
    false
  }
}
```

And then:

```
foo {xy:(Int, Int) => xy._1 == xy._2}

foo {xyz:(Int, Int, Int) => xyz._1 == xyz._2 && xyz._2 == xyz._3}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work. But the ._1 is bit inconvenient. Lets wait for other answers for few days.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your example, the given functions extends respectively `Function2` and `Function3`, and these traits and `Function` don't have any common superclass (other than `Any`), so you won't be able to find a valid signature for your function. That's why you have to play with `Tuple`s and their `_x` notations.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle more than 5 arguments, you can overload `foo` for however many arguments you need. Scala (currently) can only handle functions of up to `Function22`, so you could cover all possibilities with 22 lines of code, and good call site usage.

```
def foo[T](f: (T) => Boolean) = true
def foo[T](f: (T, T) => Boolean) = true
def foo[T](f: (T, T, T) => Boolean) = true
def foo[T](f: (T, T, T, T) => Boolean) = true
def foo[T](f: (T, T, T, T, T) => Boolean) = true
// snip
def foo[T](f: (T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T) => Boolean) = true
```

Elegant, no. Works, yes.